# Modify SVG in the background

Tags: javascript, svg

I have SVG icons of some elements. These elements are for example road signals on the level crossing. If a road signal is shining RED light, I change the appropriate SVG element's fill to red.

Now I have these elements in a menu, and I want each of them to have it's icon, but also that this icon represents its lamp state. So when the lamp state changes, the icon at the appropriate element also changes.

I did this before in Java (GWT) and I did it by loading the icon into a variable in a helper class (SvgHelper) and then anytime I wanted to display icon of particular element anywhere, I called svgHelper.getIcon(element) and it modified the svg, that it has stored in a variable, (in the background) and then returned me new cloned SVGImage that I could the put anywhere. So I only had one icon, changed its state, cloned it and returned.

Now when I want to do it in javascript, it seems, that to work with the SVG in any way, it has to be in the DOM first.

Is there a way to work with the SVG "in the background" so that it is not in the DOM? Because I would rather change multiple SVG properties and once finished then put the SVG in the DOM. Also I target the elements by ID and there can be multiple of those icons on a single page, so the IDs would collide.

I tried using **svg.js** and import my svg from string, but from what I understood the library actually requires some div to work in, so it adds it to the DOM.

In java I was doing it using [this](https://github.com/laaglu/lib-gwt-svg) library and since it is in the end compiled to JS, there should be a way to do it.

Comment: Your previous GWT approach has most likely inserted the SVG images into the DOM. So why not do it like this again? And I don't buy the *do it in the background* requirement. If it is really so slow (several seconds or more) that it would be a problem if some icons change the color earlier than others, you can write a few additional lines of Javascript code that first collects all the affected DOM elements and then applies the chance at once.

Comment: Well it is not about the performance, but that I have one svg file with IDs and if I would copy this svg into multiple parts of the webpage, I cannot really target them by this ID, because there would be many. I thought that there is some other way like putting the SVG into an iframe or somethink like that. But as I am writing it I guess I could strip down the ids from the resulting SVG, leaving just the main SVG with ids, from which I will create all the other icons every time.

Comment: And you are right, the GWT library really does add the SVG to the DOM, I should have checked the library source before.

Comment: In case could be useful try [svgson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgson) which converts `svg` into _Object_ to manipulate and so on…

Comment: Could be interesting, since I only need the string to put in v-html directive, I could change properties in an object and then get the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since even the GWT library adds the SVG to the DOM, I ended up doing just that. So I have some object which I have in a DOM somewhere outside of the screen, target the element by ID, change its properties. Onec the SVG is ready, I put it in its destination using vuejs's v-html directive.